# Trying to assign contents of a variable to params[:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I need to grab the contents of a form before the submit key is pressed in order to save the user input. If the form is submitted and validation fails then the user input is lost.

I have the main contents of the form working ok with session variables. However I want to take the params[:images] from paperclip and save that to a column in a table and then load it back into params[:images]

My form has

```
<div class="field" title="You may attach one or more documents to this observation: Pictures, word documents, spreadsheets, etc">
  <%= f.label :Upload_attachments %><br>
  <%= file_field_tag "images[]", type: :file,  multiple: true %>
</div>
```

in the respond_to for create, I can write the contents of params[:images] to a table with

```
 if params[:images]
      temp_data = TempDatum.create( item: '2',  data: params[:images])
    end
```

That works and results in something like the following in data

> [#,
>   @original_filename="2016 06 13 capture.JPG",
>   @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data;
>   name=\"images[]\"; filename=\"2016 06 13
>   capture.JPG\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">]

in my create, I have the following

```
 @image_data = TempDatum.last
     if @image_data.present?
       # params[:images] = @image_data.data
       params[:images] =  '[#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0xe4a46e8 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:C:/Users/cmendla/AppData/Local/Temp/RackMultipart20160614-13124-iib9h0.JPG>, @original_filename="2016 06 13 capture.JPG", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"images[]\"; filename=\"2016 06 13 capture.JPG\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">]'
       $temp1 = 'got here'
     end
```

I have tried various ways of trying to get the contents of TempDatum.data into the params[:images] The way it is now, I was simply trying to take the raw data from the data field in the table.

What do I need to do to set params[:images] to the values in TempDatum.data for a given record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are attempting to do will not work and is grossly over-engineered.  The `params` object is a `ActionController::Parameters`, therefore, it will never be accessible outside the context of the controller that has created it (can't access it in the view).

Here is what you need to do:

First, make sure you are instantiating the object you are attempting to create in the `new` action and make sure you map your form to that object.

Second, you need to instantiate the object again at the beginning of your `create` action.  You should then have a conditional to the `save` action of that object.  If the `save` fails due to validation, `render :new` and the form will hold the inputted data.

```
def new
    # map this to your form_for
    @object = Model.new
end

def create
    @object = Model.new(params)
    #  other logic...
    if @object.save
        # do what you need to do if everything is valid...
    else
        render :new
    end
end
```